# How to save file to the current directory with roslaunch?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i write a simple C++ program to save an image

```
cv::imwrite(filename,visual_img);
```

when i run it directly from Eclipse, the image is saved in the current directory (the directory where the Eclipse project file is in). but when i run it with roslaunch

```
<node pkg="testProg" type="testProg" name="testProg" />
```

the image is saved in home/.ros

so what should i do to save it to the current directory?

p.s. i encounter the same problem when i try to load the image. always fail to load if i put the image in the current directory when i run it by roslaunch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57075/how-to-save-file-to-the-current-directory-with-roslaunch?/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [attributes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes) section on the roslaunch wiki page.

Using the "cwd" attribute, you can specify that the node should be started using the executable's directory as its working-directory.  The default behavior is to use $ROS_HOME directory.

For example:

```
<launch>
  <node name="test" pkg="my_package" type="my_node" cwd="node" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2013-03-05**:
a million thanks! it works.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-05**:
However, it is generally better to use $ROS_HOME subdirectories for files you want to write.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what I do to run the nodes in the current directory:

```
ROS_HOME=`pwd` roslaunch foo.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6